# Change WordPress multisite to sub-folder installation

Tags: multisite

I have an existing sub-folder based WordPress multisite that I would like to change so that the WordPress core files are stored in a sub-folder, but my URL stays the same.  I'm following the instructions here:

https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-ii-with-url-change

But for Multisite, there is nowhere I can find in the Dashboard to change "WordPress address (URL)" or "Site address (URL)", i.e., steps 3 and 4.  I would prefer to do this via "Method II" as outlined on this page.

Can I simply just go into phpMyAdmin and manually update the relevant db fields for these steps and follow the rest of the instructions as is?  And if so, what would be the relevant db fields I would change?

Answer (score 0):

Top Admin bar of a multisite: Choose My Sites, Network Admin, Settings.

You have to be a SuperAdmin to do this. Note that the super-admin admin page is different from the first sub-site's Admin page.

Link location is https://www.domain.com/wp-admin/network/settings.php , where you change the domain name to your domain.

** **CORRECTION** **

I was thinking of the Network, Sites, then editing the main site (site ID = 1) .  Equivalent URL is https://www.domain.com/wp-admin/network/site-settings.php?id=1

The values you need to change are 'SiteURL' and "Home", but they are not editble on this screen. You will need to get into the wp-options table to edit those values.

Those are the values you would change to change all site domains. And you might even have to use a Search/Replace plugin to change the domain name in other areas of the domain.

But if your intent is to move the site to something like public_html/newplace , then you just need to change that on your hosting place to point your domain to the new folder. After you have copied all files from the public_html/oldplace to public_html/newplace .

I don't believe there are any places in the database that specify the full path to the site. That's a hosting thing.

Comment: There aren't any editable fields on that page where you can change any WordPress URL.  At least not in any WordPress multisite (I have a couple) that I have.   I think I'll try modifying the database directly and see what happens